# How do I load a WASM module in a Vue component without initializing the module every time?

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, rust, webassembly

I have created a Rust library of type `cdylib` using

```
cargo web build --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

I use a modified version of the "rust-wasm-loader" NPM package to build and load the WASM file. rust-wasm-loader uses this as a way to use the Rust code:

```
const wasm = require('./main.rs')
wasm.initialize().then(module => {
    // Use your module here 
    const doub = module.cwrap('doub', 'number', ['number'])
    console.log(doub(21))
})
```

I do not want to initialize the module every time I want to use the code. How do I load the module and use it like a library?

Comment: You could just capture a reference to the module as a global variable? You don’t need anything sophisticated just because it is WebAssembly

Comment: What do you want the behavior of your component to be if it is used *before* the WebAssembly module has been loaded/initialized? I think the solution will be the same as what you would do to support code-splitting / asynchronous components. I don't know Vue, but I've used similar techniques for React. I second the point around "it's not special because it's WebAssembly".

Answer (score 2):

Since the loading of WebAssembly is asynchronous and may actually take some time for large modules, you need to handle the state when the module is not loaded, and then let the rest of the application know when the WebAssembly module is loaded.

You do not say how you are handling state in your Vue application, but if you are e.g. using Vuex you can do something like this:

```
const doubPlugin = store => {
  wasm.initialize().then(module => {
    const doub = module.cwrap('doub', 'number', ['number'])

    store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
      if (mutation.type === 'DOUB_REQUEST') {
        store.commit('DOUB_RESULT', doub(mutation.payload))
      }
    })

    store.commit('DOUB_READY')
  })
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  plugins: [doubPlugin]
})
```

I've done a similar thing in an Elm/WebAssembly application ([relevant JavaScript](https://github.com/evestera/json-typegen-elm-wasm/blob/master/src/index.js)), so if you want to see how this can be applied in practice you can check that out.

Answer (score 1):

Making a wrapper JS module that performs initialization and re-exports the promise seems like the most straightforward approach.

```
// main.js
module.exports = require("./main.rs").initialize().then(module => {
  return {
    doub: module.cwrap('doub', 'number', ['number'])
  };
});
```

Then anything can do

```
require("./main.js").then(api => {
  console.log(api.doub(21));
});
```

and will always get the same module. Or alternatively you could invert the async part and do

```
// main.js
const api = require("./main.rs").initialize().then(module => {
  return {
    doub: module.cwrap('doub', 'number', ['number'])
  };
});

exports.doub = async function (val) {
  return (await api).doub(val);
};
```

Then users of your module could do

```
const api = require("./main.js");
api.doub(21).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I am using your first example. the result is a fullfilled promise. I still have to add a .then( api => {}). Is there way to just call api.doub(2)?

Comment: If you wanted, but it would require a separate side-channel to make sure the module has loaded first. From an API level that's not an ideal design. I think your approach of using method 1 and caching it is a good one for what you want, as long as you're sure it exists by the time you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class to wrap the WebAssembly loading and created a cwrap for every function:

```
class mkLib {
  ready = false
  _mod = require("./main.rs").initialize().then(module => {
    this._mod = module
    this.doub = module.cwrap('doub', 'number', ['number'])
    this.ready = true
  })

}
export default mkLib
```

In the Vue component's `data` there is a variable for the new class and in `watch` I wait for a change in the `ready` property:

```
data () {
  return {
    mod: new mkLib,
    ready: false
  }
},
watch: {
  'mod.ready': function () {
    this.ready = true
    // now this.mod.FUNC(PARAMS) can be used
    console.log(this.mod.doub(20))
  }
}
```